# Common ingredient between two disinfectants?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I find one of the most powerful associations to be odour, placing me very clearly in a time and place. Recently we were using [Dettol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dettol) in the house and I was reminded very clearly of a another disinfectant my grandmother used to use to clean greyhound kennels called [Jeyes Fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeyes_Fluid).

Is there a common ingredient between the two of them? If, so what is it; if not why do they smell similar (IMO)?

Comment: Side note: There is no reason to use disinfectants around the house.

Comment: @Karl Curious as to how you're able to elicit my specific needs from the post above and pronounce thus? I said I was using it _in_ the house, not _around_ the house ;-)

Comment: Unless your house is a hospital or used for commercial food production,  disinfectants are superflous, and potentially detrimental to your health &  environment and definitely to your wallet.

Comment: @Karl If this were Wikipedia, I'd be tagging your comments under unfounded opinion or subjective observation and moving that they be deleted. They have no relevance to the original question at all so I'd suggest in future you refrain from making ones of this nature

Comment: @nonand I'm sorry if my opinion offended you, but we are talking chemistry here, and that is the wrong place to hide a safety concern out of politeness. Subtract the comment about your wallet, it is admittedly out of line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dettol's active ingredient is chloroxylenol.
Jeye's fluid's is 4-chloro-m-cresol.

It's still possible that both disinfectants simply have an added scent to make them smell "clean". However the active ingredients above are both phenols and will likely have a similar phenolic smell (think hospitals), though I haven't sampled them both myself.

Comment: Fascinating stuff, thank you. Some more on the characteristics of the "phenolic smell" here: http://perfumeshrine.blogspot.ie/2012/02/definition-terpenic-phenolic.html